# Launch browser popup and POST to a different site

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have two websites (ASP.NET MVC 3, but I don't think that's very important). The first one has a button; when the user clicks that button, the site needs to make a POST call to the second website and display the result in a popup. The result is a wizard of sorts - it has several steps that require clicking buttons. The final step should close the popup.

My main problem is: how can I make the popup AND the POST? I can do a POST from the code-behind in my first site, but if I just display the resulting HTML in the popup window (replacing its content or something), the browser still knows that the page came from the first site, so the next button click tries to go to the first site. I need the popup to know its contents came from the second site.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

View Site A in browser. POST to Site B. Site B sends minimal HTML to browser, and that HTML creates the popup.

Does that help? Can clarify further if needed.

Comment: Please do... how do I get the result from the POST to site B to make it to the browser? If I return it in a view from site A, the browser still thinks site A opened it up... doesn't it?

Comment: Is the POST originating from the server for Site A or from the browser that is viewing Site A?  If the POST originates from the server for Site A and is then sent to the browser, the browser treats Site A as a sort of proxy -- the browser thinks the response from Site B is coming from Site A.  If the POST originates from the browser that is viewing Site A, the browser should recognize the origin of the response as Site B.